# disable click event handler for a duration of time

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind, settimeout, unbind

I've already looked at similar questions but the answers provided involve buttons and not div elements. When I click the div element with id `click`, the click event handler is disabled by `unbind()` and sets a timer for 2 seconds. After 2 seconds, the click event handler should be enabled again by `bind()`. The problem is that the click event handler doesn't seem to get "rebound". I am appending text to another div element to check if the click event handler is active.

Here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eQUne/).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Another approach to the whole problem is not to bother with unbinding and rebinding and just use a "disabled" flag:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   var clickDisabled = false;
   $('#click').click(function(){
      if (clickDisabled)
         return;

      // do your real click processing here

      clickDisabled = true;
      setTimeout(function(){clickDisabled = false;}, 2000);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are rebinding the function the second time you are binding just a subset of all your code - all it does it output bound to the status, but it doesn't contain any of the code for doing a timeout a second time.

Also, you will like the `.one()` function.

I've fixed up your code here: https://jsfiddle.net/eQUne/6/

```
function bindClick() {
    $('#click').one('click', function() {
        $('#status').append("bound ");
        setTimeout(bindClick, 2000);
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    bindClick();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#click').click(function(){

    $('#click').unbind('click');
    $('#status').append("unbound ");

    setTimeout(
        function(){
            $('#click').bind('click',function(){

            });
            $('#status').append("bound ");           
        },
        2000
        );
    });
});
```

You misspelled setTimeout and your "bound" message was being appended only on click.

Answer (score 0):

If I got what you were asking correctly, this should work:

```
<div id="click" >time out</div>
<div id="status"></div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#click').click(unbindme);

    $('#status').html('bound'); 

    function unbindme()
    {
        $('#click').unbind('click');
        $('#status').html('unbound');
    
        setTimeout(function(){
            alert('here');
            $('#status').html('bound'); 
            $('#click').click(unbindme);   
        }, 2000);
    }
}
```

Check it out here: https://jsfiddle.net/eQUne/

Answer (score 0):

I answer your question but just don't kill yourself :)) Just kidding... Your code is fine just a typo: `setTimeOut` should be `setTimeout` (the O should be o)