# On an event fire a function immediately but wait x seconds untill it is able to run again?

Tags: javascript

I have an event called customevent. When this event occurs I need to toggle a class on a div.

This is working however the event sometimes fires multiple times in quick succession. When this happens the class is added and removed again which is not what I want.

```
  $(document).on('customevent', function(event, data) {
        $('.class').toggleClass('toggle-class');
  });
```

When the event occurs I need the class to be immediately toggled. However I need the class to not be able to be toggled for 1 second even if the event continues to fire. The following is not working.

```
  var is_blocked;

  $(document).on('customevent', function(event, data) {
      if (is_blocked !== true) {
        $('.class').toggleClass('toggle-class');
        is_blocked = true;
        setTimeout(function(){
          is_blocked = false; 
        }, 1000);
      }
  });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [disable click event handler for a duration of time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8335177/disable-click-event-handler-for-a-duration-of-time)

Answer (score 1):

Why not set is_blocked to a timestamp rather than a boolean? Something like:

```
var blocked_time = 0;

$(document).on('customevent', function(event, data) {
    if (blocked_time + 1000 < new Date().getTime()) {
        $('.class').toggleClass('toggle-class');
        blocked_time = new Date().getTime();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are very close, but no sigar

```
var is_blocked = false;

$(document).on('customevent', function(event, data) {
    if (!is_blocked) {

        $('.class').toggleClass('toggle-class');

        is_blocked = true;

        setTimeout(function(){
            is_blocked = false; 
        }, 1000);
    }

    is_blocked = true; 
    //I'll be set to true, and in a second ill be false
    //thanks to the timeout. This might not be a stable solution
    //because what happens if the function is spammed for over a second?
});
```

You need to set `is_blocked` to `true` every time the function runs independent of the `if-statement`.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the `debounce` (or `throttle` in lodash) function, which might be used like this

```
var throttled = debounce(function() {
  // your actions will be executed at max
  // once every 1000ms
}, 1000);

$(document).on('event', throttled);
```

On the subject: https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function